# How to find requirements by keywords using DOORS DXL

Tags: keyword, ibm-doors

I have identified 3-5 keywords for every requirement in module-A. Each keyword is separated by a comma. Now I want to search every requirement in module-B to see which of them have words that match each of the key words.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for. You might have to specify if none of these solutions I'm about to propose are exactly what you're looking for.

If you're trying to create a filter which displays only objects with those keywords in your current view, you can create an advanced filter by first going to filter (Tools > Filter > Define) and then select the Advanced button on the bottom left of the filter menu that appears.

At this point you can create custom rules for the filter. I would just create an individual rule for each word with the following definition:

```
Attribute: Object Text
Condition: contains
Value: <insert word here>
Match Case: uncheck
Regular Expression: uncheck
```

Then select the Add button to add the rule to the list of available rules in the Advanced Options.

At this point you can select multiple rules in the list of available rules and you can AND/OR these rules together to create a custom filter for the view that you want.

So that's for if you're trying to create a custom view with just objects containing specific words.

If you're talking about writing DXL code to automatically spit out requirements that have a particular word in it. You can use the something that looks like this:

```
Object o
String s
int offset, len

for o in entire (current Module) do
{
  if (isDeleted(o)) continue

  s = o."Object Text"""
  if findPlainText(s, "<insert word here>", offset, len, false)
  {
    print identifier(o)  // or replace this line with however you want to display object
  }
}
```

Hope this is helpful. Cheers!

Edit:

To perform actions on a comma separated list, one at a time, you can use a while loop with some sort of search function that cuts off words one at a time.

```
void processWord (string someWord, Module mTarget, Object oSource)
{
  Object oTarget
  string objID = identifier(oSource)

  for oTarget in mTarget do
  {
    if (<someWord in oTarget Object Text>) // edit function as necessary to do this
    {
      if (oTarget."Exists""" == "")
        oTarget."Exists" = objID
      else
        oTarget."Exists" = oTarget."Exists" "," objID
    }
  }
}

int offset, len
string searchCriteria
Module mSource = read("<path of source module>", true)
Module mTarget = edit("<path of target module>", true)
Object oSource

for oSource in mSource do // can use "for object in entire(m)" for all objects
{
  if (oSource != rqmt) continue // create conditions specific to your module here

  searchCriteria = oSource."Search Criteria"""
  while (findPlainText(searchCriteria, ",", offset, len, false))
  {
    processWord(searchCriteria[0:offset-1], mTarget, oSource)

    searchCriteria = searchCriteria[offset+1:]
  }
}

processWord(searchCriteria, mTarget, oSource) // for last value in comma separated list
```

Comment: Thank you fro the response. I am sorry I should have added more details. So in a column in my module I list keywords, separated by a comma.=, eg run, jump, sleep, eat

Comment: Thank you for the response. Sorry I should have added more details. So in a column in my source module I list 5 keywords ea separated by a comma, i.e. run, jump, sleep, eat. I need my DXL code to loop through the object of my target module and search for each word from the source module individually. If found do something, like put the ID of the object in a column in the target module, then go back and pick up the second word, i.e., jump, go to the target module, search and if found put the ID of the object in the source module into an object in the target module.

Comment: I know how to loop through the object in a source module and search for anything using Regexp and then doing anything, but don't know how to pick up just one word from a list of words separated by a comma and search for it (i.e., for each word not the all of the words) in the target module, then go back and pick up the second word and search for it in the target module and so on.

Comment: I hope I'm understanding you correctly. When said "column in a source module", I assumed you meant there was only one object with those five keywords, not every object in that source module has five different key words. If it is the former, I edited my original post for some code that might be useful to you. Let me know if there's something I'm missing in what you said.

Comment: Thank you DC United. Yes as I read my own text I see how inaccurate and ambiguous it is. I apologize. So I will try to explain the problem more accurately now.

Comment: So, I have two modules, source and target. The source module has a list of requirements (objects) in the o."Object Text" column, a column for the Absolute Number (o."Absolute Number") and a third column called Search Criteria (o."Search Criteria").  The Search Criteria column has 3 to 6 words in it, separated by a space (it could be separated by a comma). The target module has a list of requirements texts (objects) in the o2."Object Text" column (these requirements/text are different than what is in the source module, although it does not matter for this exercise).

Comment: So what I want my code to do is this (pseudo code): from the source module look at the first object (requirements), pick up the first word in the Search Criteria column - lets call it the first search word in the string (not all the words in the attribute of the object, but only the first word), also pick up (store in memory) the o."Absolute Number" of the object, go to the target module, search for the 'search word' in the o2."Object Text", if found, put the o."Absolute Number" (i.e., the id of the source module object) in a column/attrivute called "Exists" in the target module (o2."Exists").

Comment: Make sure that the search word is searched in every object in the target module and the id of the source module is put in the target module Exists column for the object where the search word is found. In other words, the search word may exist in many objects in the target module. Once the search reaches the end of the target module, the code should go back to the first/same object in the source module and pick up the second word in the Search Word column, go to the target module and search for it. Important: the code should append the source module id (if it finds search match) in the target

Comment: module object, not over-write what may already exist in the target module Exist column. This is because during an earlier search, the code may have found a match and put the id in the Exists column/attribute and so it should not over-write that.

Comment: Once all the words in the first source module object have been searched, the code  should go to the second object in the source module and pick up the first word in the Search Criteria column/attribute of the object (2nd object) and search for it in the target module objects. If found, append the id of the source module object in the Exists column/attribute of the target module object where it found a match.

Comment: I know this explanation was lengthy but I hope I am clearer as to what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey HamNaz, that makes alot more sense, but just to make sure I'm understanding you correctly. The end result will be that the "Exists" attribute in the target module contains the module id of the every object in the source module with the following property: one or more comma separated word in the "search criteria" attribute of the source module is found in the target module's object text.

Comment: I went ahead and updated the code per my previous comment. I added placeholders for code you'll need to write yourself. First, you need to figure out how you classify an object as a requirement in your source module, and write some code specifically to skip over the objects that aren't requirements. You can also filter your view so that it only shows the objects that you want processed. Second, you need to modify processWord() with your regexp code to determine whether the word exists in the target object. You said you know how to do this in your previous comments, so I didn't bother.

Comment: DC United, I salute you in appreciation! Thank you so much. I will try over the weekend and am exited to see it work. I do this a lot, once every week with large modules, running into thousands of objects/requirements. This code/tool identifies and suggests reqs that have the word(s) that I need to check in the target module, per keywords in the source module. Thank you again. This will automate my work. Cheers